# 1-D Random Walk Analysis on Transient/Recurrent

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

If we consider the 1-d random walk $(X_n)_{n \in N}$ on the set of all integers with transition probability that $p_{ij} = p$ if $j = i + 1$ and $p_{ij} = 1-p$ if $j = i - 1$, **how can we obtain the $p_{00}^{(2n+1)}$ and $p_{00}^{(2n)}$**. I think we may assume $p_{00}^{(2n)}$ as the number of ways to move $n$ times forward and $n$ times backward. Also, **how can I show whether the state 0 is transient/recurrent depending on the value of $p$?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $p_{00}^{(2n)}$ is the probability rather than the number of ways.   For the transient/recurrent, you could show that the probability of ever returning is not $1$ or is $1$

Comment: Hi @Henry, thanks for your reply. I think what I am interested is that how we can deduce the expression of $p_{00}^{(2n)}$ as the number of times moving forward and the number of times moving backward. I noticed that the $p$ should be the probability so I don't know how to connect it with the number of times of moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Obviously, $p_{00}^{(2n+1)} = 0$, for any $n \in N$.
   Since this is a 1-d random walk, we know that **$X_{2n} \sim Binomial (2n, p)$**. It can be showed: taking a particular ordered sequence of $n$ forward steps and $n$ backward steps is $p^n(1-p)^n$, thus we can obtain
   $$
   p_{00}^{(2n)} = \frac{(n+n)!}{n!n!}p^n(1-p)^n = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!}p^n(1-p)^n.
   $$
2. By Stirling's formula,
   $$
   p_{00}^{(2n)} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!}p^n(1-p)^n = \frac{[4p(1-p)]^n}{\sqrt{n \pi}},
   $$
   we let
   $$
   a_n = \frac{[4p(1-p)]^n}{\sqrt{n \pi}},
   $$
   and then we can use the ratio test for $a_n$.
   $$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = 4p(1-p),
   $$
   since $p \in [0,1]$ and $4p(1-p) \in [0,1]$. This indicates that the convergence of test depends on the value of $p$.

1). Consider $p = \frac{1}{2}$, we can obtain
$$
a_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}
$$
Since $a_n \sim \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$, then we can get
$$
\sum a_n = \sum p_{00}^{(2n)} = + \infty,
$$
which indicates the state $0$ is **positive recurrent**.

2). Consider $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$, the ratio test shows that $\sum p_{00}^{(2n)}$ is convergent. By Cauchy criterion,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{00}^{(2n)} = 0,
$$
which implies the state $0$ is **transient**.